# Visual Studio 2013 express SSE2 disable

Tags: visual-c++, sse2

I tried to rebuild a MSVC 2013 project with disabled sse2 features but it didn't helped.Should i rebuild glew and GLFW libraries that are used?The project is motogame,a part of motocoin http://motocoin.org/ .I can't run this game because my processor didn't support this feature.After the rebuild with disabled sse2 feature .exe did not start.Debugger show that is a illegal instruction cvtsi2sd.What can i do with it?

Comment: Or buy a new computer, because apparently it's over a decade old. Without SSE2 support you'll be out of luck a lot - fallback for pre-SSE2 is slowly disappearing.

Answer (score 2):

Have you used /arch:SSE  compiler option  per http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/7t5yh4fd.aspx  ?
And yes, you need to rebuild all libraries, especially if you have source code